# Is there a way to get the execution time of individual method calls using DotTrace?

Tags: c#, dottrace

I would like to figure out the execution time of individual calls of a method. So if a method gets called 3 times, I can see the total time it needed to execute. Since the execution time might vary in every call I would like to see the individual time.

Is there a way to see that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately, it is not possible.
Also please note that total function time may be inaccurate in Tracing/Line-by-line profiling modes: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profiling_Guidelines__Choosing_the_Right_Profiling_Mode.html#tracing

You can try to use Timeline profiling mode in this case. If the calls of the method are distributed in time, you can select a time interval with only one call and get the time of this call.